# Code examples for ONLY_BILL_FIRST_AUTHORIZER

Tags: eosio-code, permissions, cpu

Can someone please add code example or describe how to only bill first authorizer?

I have tried but can't get it to work.

[image]
Thanks!

Comment: when you put two actions in one transaction, it will only bill the first action's authorizer

Comment: Thanks. I tried putting two actions in one transaction, where the first action's authorizer is the contract account. But still, the second action's authorizer is billed. I also tried to add two authorizers for the second action, where the first authorizer is the contract account. And again - the second authorizer is billed for cpu and net.

Comment: because the feature has not been activated yet, wait for the bps' proposal

Comment: @bjørn-omsland can share your code?

Comment: I need Code examples for ONLY_BILL_FIRST_AUTHORIZER, very thankful.

Answer (score 2):

The ONLYBILL1ST proposal has now been approved by 15 Block producers. I have tested and OnlyBillFirstAuthorizer is working now.

I'm using eos-sharp. But it's very similar to eos-js. It's very simple. Just add the account you want to bill for the transaction first in the 'authorization'-part.

```
    //Add the private keys 
    List<string> lstSignProviders = new List<string>();
    lstSignProviders.Add("privateKeyForOnlyBillFirstAuthorizer"); //ONLY_BILL_FIRST_AUTHORIZER
    lstSignProviders.Add("privateKeyForTheAccountExecuting");

    Eos eos = new Eos(new EosConfigurator()
    {
        HttpEndpoint = eosHttpEndpoint,
        ChainId = eosChainId,
        ExpireSeconds = 20,
        SignProvider = new EosSharp.Core.Providers.DefaultSignProvider(lstSignProviders)
    });

    var result = eos.CreateTransaction(new Transaction()
    {
        actions = new List<EosSharp.Core.Api.v1.Action>(){
            new EosSharp.Core.Api.v1.Action()
            {
                account = "eosio.token",
                authorization = new List<PermissionLevel>()
                {
                    new PermissionLevel() {actor = "accountToBillForCpuNet", permission = "active" },
                    new PermissionLevel() {actor = fromAccount, permission = "active" }
                },
                name = "transfer",
                data = new { from = fromAccount,
                                to = toAccount,
                                quantity = "1.0000 EOS",
                                memo = ""}
            }
        }
    }).Result;`enter code here`
```

Comment: While correct, your original question asked to provide code example. If you are going to answer your original question you should at least provide a code example for future readers.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I have added code example now.